# Is this a valid/good technique for avoiding global variables with C in embedded software?

Tags: c, global-variables

I've looked long and hard into this topic of avoiding global variables and have come up with a way of doing it that I haven't really seen anywhere else in my searches which leads me to believe it's maybe not a great way of doing it (or I'm just not wording my search correctly).

As an example I have something like this:

```
int16_t DataProcessing(uint8_t CallType, struct DataStruct *DataIO)
{

     int16_t RetVal;
     static struct DataStruct StaticDataStuct;

     switch (CallType)
         {
         case FIRSTCASE: RetVal = FirstCaseProcessing(&StaticDataStuct,DataIO); break;
         case SECONDCASE: RetVal = SecondCaseProcessing(&StaticDataStuct,DataIO); break;
         ...
         etc
         ...
         }

     return RetVal;

}

int16_t FirstCaseProcessing(struct DataStruct *StaticData, struct DataStruct *NewData)
{

// Do what you need to do here

}
```

Same idea for any other routines that are called.

I have also done wrapper functions to call DataProcessing() that makes the whole thing much easier to read and for new people using it in the future. So, for example:

```
int16_t FirstCase(uint8_t Address, uint16_t Data)
{

     struct DataStruct NewData;

     NewData.Address = Address;
     NewData.Data= Data;

     return DataProcessing(FIRSTCASE, &NewData);

}
```

So, what seems good, is that other than for the interrupts such as UART and timers, I have no global variables at all. (I still think getting in and out of interrupts as fast as possible is better than having an interrupt call something to store data in a static variable somewhere, but am happy to be persuaded otherwise.)

What is [maybe] bad is that I'm passing stuff through three functions in the interests of avoiding globals and making it more readable (assuming it's not just *me* that finds it readable!)

I would say that I have been given a 72MHz embedded 32 bit processor to do what could be done with an eight bit processor, running at a fraction of the speed (assuming it had enough RAM). So speed is not an issue, although I'm interested in opinions on whether this is a good style for when speed *might* be more of an issue.

I've seen the C++ style of having .c files and having static variables that any function within that .c file can see and access (but external files cannot), passing values/pointers etc in and out with accessor functions, but they seem to use what I would think are variables that are "global" to the file (or local to the file depending how you want to look at it!). Also, it's possible to have one function that stores a static variable and simply passes a pointer to that static variable to anything that wants to access it. I'm wondering whether that would be going OTT?

Does my idea seem good/bad/terrible?

Many thanks for any advice and all the TL;DRs I'm probably going to get. ;~)

Comment: Whats inside DataStruct ?

Comment: Anything that is needed for a particular part of the program. For example in one there is Port states, timer values, flags, card number, port number.

Comment: It would be useful to know why you are averse to file-wide globals? Having the static structure in the function is negligibly different to having it in the file, assuming all your functions are in the same file.  Either method has problems with multi-threading; but that may or may not be relevant.  I think we need to know more context if possible.

Comment: I'm not necessarily averse to file-wide globals at all. I have seen some people say these are acceptable and others say avoid them. I wondered whether I could find a universally acceptable way. There is no multi-threading whatsoever in this; it's purely run-to-complete style software.

Comment: Then try dynamic global variables. It's a list of variables created on execution of the program, and they are accessed by an identifier through a function.

Answer (score 0):

OP:Does my idea seem good/bad/terrible?

**Good**  OP is not yet OTT.

Avoiding global variables in embedded designs is a good goal primarily for the sake of maintenance.  Information hiding (making data local to a function or object) is key to controlling the myriad of interactions and making debugging easier.  This is especially true with OP faster (and likely larger memory) processor.

---

An alternative - hide data in file scope.

OP solution appears hierarchical as at `DataProcessing()`, command and Input/Output parameters are given and details of `DataStruc` are known at this level.

I'm aim for more of a data driven approach, using a pointer or index and a set of routines.  Say in an embedded program I need, at most, Sally_N instances of a Sally variable.  Here my data is not global, but hidden in the file scope of Sally.c.  Thus the data and its detailed fields are hidden far from the higher level code that uses it.  In OP's approach, the details of `DataStruct` are known to the higher level function `DataProcessing()`.

```
// Sally.h
struct Sally_t;  // Does not expose the fields
extern struct Sally_t *Sally_Init(...);
extern void Sally_DoThis(struct Sally_t *, ...);
extern void Sally_DoThat(struct Sally_t *, ...);

// Sally.c
struct Sally_t { int a, ... };  // Structure details
static struct Sally_t Sally_Data[Sally_N];// file scope prevents global exposure
struct Sally_t *Sally_Init(...);
void Sally_DoThis(struct Sally_t *, ...);
void Sally_DoThat(struct Sally_t *, ...);
```